# How to install requests module for Python 3.1 ubuntu server 10.04?

Tags: server, 10.04, python3, pip

I have a ubuntu server.(10.04)

I don't install requests module. I try pip and other methods. Usually ;

```
$ sudo pip install requests 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError, match_hostname
ImportError: cannot import name CertificateError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from backports.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError, match_hostname
ImportError: No module named backports.ssl_match_hostname

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.5', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.1.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.1.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2382, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.1.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ssl_match_hostname
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.1.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _implementation import CertificateError, match_hostname
ImportError: No module named _implementation
```

I guess I have already setup pip 3.1. But following

```
$ pip -V
```

Then I see same problem. How to install requests module for Python 3.1 ubuntu server 10.04?

Comment: I really REALLY highly extremely recommend and ask that you update yourself to 14.04 where you will find less python issues (A lot less) than staying with a 4 year old version of Ubuntu.

Comment: 14.04 is a stable, LTS version.  It is true that upgrading will solve many issues.

Answer (score 1):

## Use PIP 3.3, not 3.1

- `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
- `sudo python get-pip.py`

> ```
> Downloading/unpacking pip
> Downloading/unpacking setuptools
> Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
> Successfully installed pip setuptools
> Cleaning up...
> ```

**Notes**

- pip 3.1 has known issues, such as these.
- [Additional Information](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)